# Java: Создание печатных форм.

Tags: печать, java, шаблоны, swing

И снова Java...

Приложение Java+Swing. Необходимо создать печатные формы, в которые потом с легкостью можно было бы передавать только данные. Возможность предпросмотра подготовленного документа. В общем все, как у взрослых...

Пытался копать в сторону Java2D, но не уверен, что пошел в правильном направление. Временное решение сделано на основе PDF (в отдельном потоке создается PDF и потом открывается программой по-умолчанию, далее через нее и идет печать), но это не есть хорошо, ибо зависим от внешних приложений. Решение ужасное - понимаю, но это первое, что пришло в голову.

Что можете посоветовать для создания печатных форм? Желательно описание форм в отдельных файлах...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Репортинговая система де-факто для java это [JasperReports](http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jasperreports-library).

Comment: Благодарю. Странно, что я на нее не наткнулся при поисках. Как я понимаю там есть и предпросмотр и экспорт в различные форматы.

Comment: Да, все есть.